# How to access virtual host in android cell phone

Tags: android

I want to access my virtual host (running on my desktop) on my android cell phone and I do not know where to start from. I searched how I can access that. Up till now what I have found is that I need to modify my android's hosts file. I tried to do so but I could not get success. I try to do that with an emulator terminal application.

Answer (score 0):

The host PC can be accessed (from within the phone emulator) using the IP address 10.0.2.2.

That is clearly stated in the [Android Emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).